# Specifying store type per environment when registering EF context

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

When registering an EF context during `ConfigureServices` at Startup is there a way to specify what store type to use at the environment level? I'd rather not recreate the startup class for integration tests just to switch store type.

**Registering Context with Single Store Type**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNet5;Trusted_Connection=True;";

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
 }
```

**Registering Context with Different Store Types**

Problems: Not fully sure this works, becomes messy with multiple contexts.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services,  IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNet5;Trusted_Connection=True;";

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
        {
          if (env.IsEnviornment("test") { options.UseInMemoryStore(); }
          else { options.UseSqlServer(connection)); }
        });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuring your DbContext to use different data stores based on environment variables is technically valid. I don't see why the sample code above should not work. For more info, checkout [Working with Multiple Environments](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html).

I add a caution, however, that EF may behave differently depending on the data store. EF7 does not try to hide differences between providers. For example, `ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN col1` works on SQL Server but fails on SQLite. EF7 migrations do not currently compensate for this and other limitations.

Comment: Attempted and the problem I come up on is "ConfigureServices can take at most a single IServiceCollection parameter." so I don't get to pass through the env when configuring the services.

Comment: As noted in [this SO reply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32556303/540776), you can receive that parameter in `Startup` constructor by injection, then saved it to a property and use it later in `ConfigureServices`. HTH