# How to get the Development/Staging/production Hosting Environment in ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I get the Development/Staging/production Hosting Environment in the `ConfigureServices` method in Startup?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Which environment are we running under?
}
```

The `ConfigureServices` method only takes a single `IServiceCollection` parameter.

Comment: why can't `IHostingEnvironment` just be injected into ConfigureServices? oversight? or a reason we need to be aware of?

Comment: See MSFT docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Comment: Use using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting; if you are using IWebHostEnvironment. It will give you IsDevelopment/IsProduction/IsStaging etc checks.

Answer (score 417, accepted):

You can easily access it in ConfigureServices, just persist it to a property during Startup method which is called first and gets it passed in, then you can access the property from ConfigureServices.

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    ...your code here...
    CurrentEnvironment = env;
}

private IWebHostEnvironment CurrentEnvironment{ get; set; } 
 
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string envName = CurrentEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
    ... your code here...
}
```

Comment: [Per the docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html#determining-the-environment-at-runtime), this method should not be used. You should instead be using `CurrentEnvironment.IsEnvironment("environmentname")`.

Comment: or `CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` / `CurrentEnvironment.IsProduction()`

Comment: @vaindil - the docs you reference don't say this method should not be used. Your example simply ignores casing, which is preferable in many cases but not a commandment

Comment: @Coruscate5 Okay, it doesn't explicitly say to NOT use this method, but it says to use the other method INSTEAD. That's virtually the same thing.

Comment: Formally, `Startup` is not a method, it's a constructor.

Comment: deprecated IHostingEnvironment env use IWebHostEnvironment env instead

Comment: Read following answer TL;DR with correct solution Configure{EnvironmentName}() || example: ConfigureProduction().

Comment: The messaging about IHostingEnvironment being deprecated does appear as described by @Mark Schultheiss, but depending on what you care about, you can use IHostEnvironment too, which is a slightly leaner base class for IWebHostEnvironment.

Comment: @tom, yes, also deprecation notice can be seen here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: IApplicationEnvironment is not recognized

Comment: This is what docs says, and there is no such sentence that leads us not to use IWebHostEnvironment injection```Inject IWebHostEnvironment into the Startup constructor. This approach is useful when the app requires configuring Startup for only a few environments with minimal code differences per environment.```

Answer (score 107):

If you need to test this somewhere in your codebase that doesn't have easy access to the IHostingEnvironment, another easy way to do it is like this:

```
bool isDevelopment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development";
```

Comment: well, short way! Keep in mind the variable name is different between "asp.net core" and "asp.net"

Comment: Wow, what a nice idea

Comment: this code only works if there is a environment variable already set, in case your project will be published using ISS on windows server may this should wont the case, in this case I advice you to set the variable on Program.cs class

Comment: This is great because it doesn't depend a specific version of .Net Core.

Answer (score 79):

### TL;DR

Set an environment variable called `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with the name of the environment (e.g. `Production`). Then do one of two things:

- Inject `IHostingEnvironment` into `Startup.cs`, then use that (`env` here) to check: `env.IsEnvironment("Production")`. **Do not** check using `env.EnvironmentName == "Production"`!
- Use either separate `Startup` classes or individual `Configure`/`ConfigureServices` functions. If a class or the functions match these formats, they will be used instead of the standard options on that environment.

  - `Startup{EnvironmentName}()` *(entire class)* || example: `StartupProduction()`
  - `Configure{EnvironmentName}()` || example: `ConfigureProduction()`
  - `Configure{EnvironmentName}Services()` || example: `ConfigureProductionServices()`

---

### Full explanation

The .NET Core docs [describe how to accomplish this](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html). Use an environment variable called `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` that's set to the environment you want, then you have two choices.

#### Check environment name

[From the docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html#determining-the-environment-at-runtime):

> The `IHostingEnvironment` service provides the core abstraction for working with environments. This service is provided by the ASP.NET hosting layer, and can be injected into your startup logic via Dependency Injection. The ASP.NET Core web site template in Visual Studio uses this approach to load environment-specific configuration files (if present) and to customize the app’s error handling settings. In both cases, this behavior is achieved by referring to the currently specified environment by calling `EnvironmentName` or `IsEnvironment` on the instance of `IHostingEnvironment` passed into the appropriate method.

**NOTE:** Checking the actual value of `env.EnvironmentName` is **not** recommended!

> If you need to check whether the application is running in a particular environment, use `env.IsEnvironment("environmentname")` since it will correctly ignore case (instead of checking if `env.EnvironmentName == "Development"` for example).

#### Use separate classes

[From the docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html#startup-conventions):

> When an ASP.NET Core application starts, the `Startup` class is used to bootstrap the application, load its configuration settings, etc. ([learn more about ASP.NET startup](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/startup.html)). However, if a class exists named `Startup{EnvironmentName}` (for example `StartupDevelopment`), and the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable matches that name, then that `Startup` class is used instead. Thus, you could configure `Startup` for development, but have a separate `StartupProduction` that would be used when the app is run in production. Or vice versa.
>
> In addition to using an entirely separate `Startup` class based on the current environment, you can also make adjustments to how the application is configured within a `Startup` class. The `Configure()` and `ConfigureServices()` methods support environment-specific versions similar to the `Startup` class itself, of the form `Configure{EnvironmentName}()` and `Configure{EnvironmentName}Services()`. If you define a method `ConfigureDevelopment()` it will be called instead of `Configure()` when the environment is set to development. Likewise, `ConfigureDevelopmentServices()` would be called instead of `ConfigureServices()` in the same environment.

Comment: Has this changed much with the .NET 6 (non-core) release?

Comment: I don't think so. still following this pattern. @DavidMays

Answer (score 43):

This can be accomplished without any extra properties or method parameters, like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    IHostingEnvironment env = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();

    if (env.IsProduction()) DoSomethingDifferentHere();
}
```

Comment: the best answer ever. thanx

Comment: This throws the following warning in .NET Core 3.0: Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'.

Comment: deprecated IHostingEnvironment env use IWebHostEnvironment env instead

Comment: Calling `BuildServiceProvider` is not recommended! see [this article](https://andrewlock.net/access-services-inside-options-and-startup-using-configureoptions/) for more details.

Answer (score 36):

In `.NET Core 2.0` MVC app / `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` v2.0.0, you can have environmental specific startup class as described by @vaindil but I don't like that approach.

You can also inject `IHostingEnvironment` into `StartUp` constructor. You don't need to store the environment variable in `Program` class.

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _currentEnvironment;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _currentEnvironment = env;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ......

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            // Requiring authenticated users on the site globally
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

            // Validate anti-forgery token globally
            config.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());

            // If it's Production, enable HTTPS
            if (_currentEnvironment.IsProduction())      // <------
            {
                config.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            }            
        });

        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Details can be viewed in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Here is the english link posted by André: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: deprecated IHostingEnvironment env use IWebHostEnvironment env instead

Answer (score 36):

Starting from ASP.NET Core 3.0, it is much simpler to access the environment variable  from both `ConfigureServices` and `Configure`.

Simply inject `IWebHostEnvironment` into the Startup constructor itself. Like so...

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _env = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //development
        }
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //development
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.0#inject-iwebhostenvironment-into-the-startup-class

Comment: but its telling on Development or not Development (Staging, Production, VST.......). It doesn't tell whether it's production or Staging or.....?

Comment: @viveknuna Simply create your own IsStaging, IsXXXXX, etc and make sure you have the matching ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to check against.

Answer (score 30):

In NET6, Startup and Program have merged into a single file, there is no `ConfigureServices` method in Startup anymore. Now you can simply use

```
builder.Environment.IsProduction() 
builder.Environment.IsStaging()
builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()
```

right after the first line

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

Answer (score 24):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#startup-method-conventions)

> Configure and ConfigureServices support environment specific versions
> of the form Configure{EnvironmentName} and Configure{EnvironmentName}Services:

You can do something like this...

```
public void ConfigureProductionServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ConfigureCommonServices(services);
    
    //Services only for production
    services.Configure();
}

public void ConfigureDevelopmentServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ConfigureCommonServices(services);
    
    //Services only for development
    services.Configure();
}

public void ConfigureStagingServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ConfigureCommonServices(services);
    
    //Services only for staging
    services.Configure();
}

private void ConfigureCommonServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Services common to each environment
}
```

Comment: This is the nicest convention

Comment: I dont see anything about this in the docs.....

Comment: @RichardDuerr This answer is about 4 years old now and the docs have changed. I've updated the link

Comment: Thanks, I tried looking and couldn't find it. Must have been blind ha

Answer (score 23):

I wanted to get the environment in one of my services.  It is really easy to do!  I just inject it to the constructor like this:

```
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public MyEmailService(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }
```

Now later on in the code I can do this:

```
if (_hostingEnvironment.IsProduction()) {
    // really send the email.
}
else {
    // send the email to the test queue.
}
```

### EDIT:

Code above is for .NET Core 2.  For version 3 you will want to use `IWebHostEnvironment`.

Comment: I'm curious why this is receiving down votes.  Is there something about this that is wrong or bad practice?  I want to learn.

Comment: I'm personally glad you included this because it helped in my use case, but my guess as to why you were downvoted is that it's not answering the original question as asked.

Answer (score 8):

Since there is no full copy & paste solution yet, based on Joe Audette's answer:

```
public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
{
   Environment = environment;
   ...
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
   {
       // Do something
   }else{
       // Do something
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The hosting environment comes from the ASPNET_ENV environment variable, which is available during Startup using the IHostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment extension method, or one of the corresponding convenience methods of IsDevelopment or IsProduction. Either save what you need in Startup(), or in ConfigureServices call:

```
var foo = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNET_ENV");
```

Comment: ```IHostingEnvironment``` is not available in ```ConfigureServices```.

Comment: No, it's not. Refer back to my answer on how to deal with it.

Comment: The environment variable is now "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"

Comment: deprecated IHostingEnvironment env use IWebHostEnvironment env instead

Comment: Works for me on dotnet core 6. I placed it in my program.cs which was then passed into my  return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) function call with environment as a parameter

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone is looking to this too. In .net core 3+ most of this is obsolete. The update way is:

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IWebHostEnvironment env,
    ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    if (env.EnvironmentName == Environments.Development)
    {
        // logger.LogInformation("In Development environment");
    }
}
```

Comment: The question specifically asks about ConfigureServices, not Configure.

Comment: This doesn't work for ConfigureServices, because you can't inject IWebHostEnvironment in ConfigureServices. So this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to read the environment name directly from the configuration with `Configuration["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"]`. This works everywhere where you can access configuration.

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Configuration["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"]);
}
```

Prerequisite is that the host was created with Host.CreateDefaultBuilder() in Programm.cs which is the default for ASP.NET Core 3.0 (and 5.0)  web apps.  If another builder is used the envars can be added with AddEnvironmentVariables() in Programm.cs.

Answer (score 3):

In Dotnet Core 2.0 the Startup-constructor only expects a IConfiguration-parameter.

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
```

How to read hosting environment there?
I store it in Program-class during ConfigureAppConfiguration
(use full BuildWebHost instead of WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder):

```
public class Program
{
    public static IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Build web host
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        return new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
                .Build()
            )
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                // Assigning the environment for use in ConfigureServices
                HostingEnvironment = env; // <---

                config
                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                  .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
                    if (appAssembly != null)
                    {
                        config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
                    }
                }

                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                if (args != null)
                {
                    config.AddCommandLine(args);
                }
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, builder) =>
            {
                builder.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                builder.AddConsole();
                builder.AddDebug();
            })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
            {
                options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
```

Ant then reads it in ConfigureServices like this:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var isDevelopment = Program.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
}
```

Comment: deprecated IHostingEnvironment env use IWebHostEnvironment env instead

Answer (score 0):

In .NET6.0 Use the following:

var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

This will say "Development" if it is in development mode.

The variable "DEV_ENVIRONMENT" also will be set to 1 in dev environment.

Answer (score -2):

For a blazor server app I did this: `Startup.cs` directly under the namespace declaration add

```
namespace myProjectName.Server

public static class myGlobals

{
    public static bool isDevelopment = true;
}
```

`Startup.cs` find the `Configure` method and the existing check for `env.IsDevelopment` and set the `static isDeveloment` declared above to `true` or `false`.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
           myGlobals.isDevelopment = true;
        }
        else false
```

In `ApplicationUser` when you are initializing the database connection or anywhere else

```
        if (myGlobals.isDevelopment)
        {
```