# How can i configure JSON format indents in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

How can i configure ASP.NET Core Web Api controller to return pretty formatted json for `Development` enviroment only?

By default it returns something like:

```
{"id":1,"code":"4315"}
```

I would like to have indents in the response for readability:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "code": "4315"
}
```

Comment: There is usually a "prettify" button in browser which will make JSON readable. Fiddler also have a special tab fro JSON.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**.NET Core 2.2 and lower**:

In your `Startup.cs` file, call the `AddJsonOptions` extension:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    });
```

Note that this solution requires `Newtonsoft.Json`.

**.NET Core 3.0 and higher**:

In your `Startup.cs` file, call the `AddJsonOptions` extension:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
    });
```

As for switching the option based on environment, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556303/1663001) should help.

Comment: Note that `SerializerSettings` is in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`, but in order to use `Formatting` you need a `using Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: This is what I needed `options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;`

Comment: In 2.x we used to add a MediaTypeMapping for Json to be "application/json" (otherwise the browser would ignore the formatting).  How do we add a similar mapping in 3.0 and higher?

Answer (score 18):

If you want to turn on this option for a single controller instead of for all JSON, you can have your controller return a JsonResult and pass the Formatting.Indented when constructing the JsonResult like this:

```
return new JsonResult(myResponseObject) { SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { Formatting = Formatting.Indented } };
```

Answer (score 10):

In .NetCore 3+ you can achieve this as follows:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {               
         options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;    
    });
```

Comment: This is the best answer now. I just submitted a suggested edit to incorporate this into DavidG's accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I used `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` with the code below for all controllers. This for .NET Core 3.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this option only for specific action, using System.Text.Json

```
return new JsonResult(myResponseObject) { SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true } };
```

Answer (score 0):

IN .NET 7, if you want to return indented JSON output and you are using controllers, you can use this in your startup code:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
            });
```

This is using the built in JSON capabilities in .NET, not using any external frameworks like Newtonsoft.