# Enforce https on one controller and http on the other

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.NET core 2.1,
I am looking for a way to enforce **https** on one controller and **http** on the other.

The following document shows how to enforce HTTPS for the whole ASP.NET core, but not for individual controller.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to make use of two action filters: one for enforcing HTTPS redirects, and another for allowing HTTP requests. The first one would be registered globally, and the second used just with controllers/actions you wish to allow HTTP traffic to. As an example:

```
[AllowHttp]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Where `AllowHttp` is defined as:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
// Inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute allows this to show
// up in the ActionExecutingContext.Filters collection.
// See the global filter's implementation.
public class AllowHttpAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
}
```

Next, the global filter:

```
// Needed for the GetEncodedUrl() extension method.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;

public class RedirectToHttpsActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Filters.Any(x => x is AllowHttpAttribute))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.IsHttps)
        {
            var insecureUri = context.HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl();
            var secureUri = insecureUri.Replace("http://", "https://");

            // As you're likely trying this out locally, you'll need to specify
            // the port to redirect to as well. You won't need this on production.
            // Change the first port to your HTTP port and the second to your HTTPS port.
            secureUri = secureUri.Replace(":49834", ":44329");

            context.Result = new RedirectResult(secureUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you'll have to register the filter globally in your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new RedirectToHttpsActionFilter());
});
```

I'm sure you could achieve the same thing with URL rewriting, but in the case where you may change your controller routes, this will carry on working without intervention.

Comment: Thank you, I thought there is a more direct way built in asp.net core. Regarding 'the global filter', is it a regular class I need to make in project?

Comment: @Dror You're welcome, and that's right. Create a new class for it. `ActionFilterAttribute` is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters` namespace.

Comment: Gotcha, can't really test it locally, since on IIS express it uses HTTP in any case. Can I ignore this filter locally?  On the other hand, In production it does seem to work!

Comment: @Dror Good question actually, but maybe the best way would be to enable SSL for IIS Express. That way, you're working in an environment that more closely mirrors production. If you go to the properties of the web project -> Debug -> Web Server Settings -> Enable SSL, that should do it for you. You'll need to include the port redirect locally for that though.

Comment: @Dror Actually, I just figured out you can get the environment from the `ConfigureServices` method, and avoid the registration of the filter when it's the development environment. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46551596/729541

Comment: Great! Good to have in any case, will try to enable locally  HTTPS on IIS express with the filter to mirror production.

Comment: yes, it works locally, in my case ports are different:   `secureUri = secureUri.Replace(":62240", ":44316");`