# Testing different IP addresses locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am implementing some code where I use a visitors IP address to determine their location. For .net core 2, this is:

```
var ipAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

But of course when I test locally I always get the loop back address `::1`. Is there a way to simulate external IP addresses while testing locally?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service for retrieving remote address. Define an interface for it and create 2 implementations and inject them [depending on the current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548948/how-to-get-the-development-staging-production-hosting-environment-in-configurese)

```
public interface IRemoteIpService
{
    IPAddress GetRemoteIpAddress();
}

public class RemoteIpService : IRemoteIpService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public RemoteIpService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public IPAddress GetRemoteIpAddress()
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
    }
}

public class DummyRemoteIpService : IRemoteIpService
{
    public IPAddress GetRemoteIpAddress()
    {
        //add your implementation
        return IPAddress.Parse("120.1.1.99");
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
if (HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
{
    services.AddScoped<IRemoteIpService, RemoteIpService>();
}
else
{
    services.AddScoped<IRemoteIpService, DummyRemoteIpService>();
}
```

Usage

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    //...
    private readonly IRemoteIpService _remoteIpService;

    public TestController(IRemoteIpService remoteIpService)
    {
        //...
        _remoteIpService = remoteIpService;
    }

    //..
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        var ip = _remoteIpService.GetRemoteIpAddress();
        return Json(ip.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting external ip for localhost, you need to send request to retrive the ip, and you could implement an extension for `ConnectionInfo` like

```
public static class ConnectionExtension
{
    public static IPAddress RemotePublicIpAddress(this ConnectionInfo connection)
    {
        if (!IPAddress.IsLoopback(connection.RemoteIpAddress))
        {
            return connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        }
        else
        {
            string externalip = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com").Replace("\n","");
            return IPAddress.Parse(externalip);
        }
    }
}
```

And use like

```
var ip = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemotePublicIpAddress();
```