# How to get environment variables from inside Main() in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to know if the code is Dev/Stage so I need to get this. I tried the code below but it seems to skip running the Configure() of Startup.cs.  Help ?

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            SeedDatabase(host);

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {


            //return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            //  .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            //  {
            //      webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            //  });




            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

                    webBuilder.ConfigureServices(services => { })
                    .Configure(app =>
                    {
                        Env = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
                    });
                });
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548948/how-to-get-the-development-staging-production-hosting-environment-in-configurese answer by toralux gets env in main()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You haven't quite explained what it is you are trying to get (the environment variables or the environment object). But based on some of the code in the question it appears like you want access to the `IWebHostEnvironment`.

That's easy. `IHost` has a [`Services`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihost.services?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHost_Services) property. You just need to request the appropriate service.

```
IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
IWebHostEnvironment env = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
// now do something with env
SeedDatabase(host);
host.Run();
```

Now if you need the environment prior to everything else, you can also access the environment from the `WebHostBuilderContext` inside of a [different overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostbuilder.configureservices?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHostBuilder_ConfigureServices_System_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_WebHostBuilderContext_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection__) of `ConfigureServices`:

```
webBuilder.ConfigureServices((ctx, services) => { 
   IWebHostEnvironment env = ctx.HostingEnvironment;
   // Do something with env
});
```

Similarly  `ConfigureAppConfiguration`, `ConfigureHostConfiguration` and `ConfigureServices` on the `IHostBuilder` (the generic host) also provide access to the `IHostEnvironment` (note lack of "Web"):

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, config) => {
      IHostEnvironment env = ctx.HostingEnvironment;
   })
   .ConfigureServices((ctx, services) => {
      IHostEnvironment env = ctx.HostingEnvironment;
   })
   .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(/* etc */ );
```

The same service collection, environments etc are used by the generic host and the web host (in addition to the added `IWebHostEnvironment`)

Side note: Usually Startup.cs isn't invoked until the first call is made to your application. That is probably why it *appears* to not be running.

Answer (score 8):

Try getting it from inside your main method, like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
}
```

Comment: What if environment name is specified from the command line?